# Start Date and End Date fill horizontal

Tags: excel, vba, date

Can't figure out how to fill excel cells horizontally... I have "Start Date" in cell "B2" and "End Date" in cell B3.

When I input the 2 dates I just fill all the cells with the days in that range, but I fill them Vertically. I would like to fill them Horizontally

Here is a picture

[image]

"Data inizio" --> Start Date
"Data fine" --> End Date

Here is what I've done until now

```
    Sub FillCal()

    ' Disable screen updates (such as warnings, etc.)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
    Dim prova As Integer
    Dim rngMerge As Range, rngCell As Range, mergeVal As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    StartD = Foglio1.Cells(2, 2)
    EndD = Foglio1.Cells(3, 2)
    For Column = 1 To EndD - StartD
        Cells(4, Column) = StartD + Column - 1
        prova = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(StartD + Column - 1, 2)
        Cells(5, Column).NumberFormat = prova
        Cells(5, Column).Value = prova
    Next Column

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") ' Change Sheet1 to your worksheet

    i = wks.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rngMerge = wks.Range("E1:E" & i) ' Find last row in column A

    With wks
    ' Loop through Column A
checkAgain:
    For Each rngCell In rngMerge
        ' If Cell value is equal to the cell value below and the cell is not empty then
        If rngCell.Value = rngCell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(rngCell) = False Then
            ' Define the range to be merged
            ' Be aware that warnings telling you that the 2 cells contain 2 differen values will be ignored
            ' If you have 2 different sums in column C, then it will use the first of those
            '  Set mergeVal = wks.Range(rngCell.Offset(0, 2), rngCell.Offset(1, 2))
            '    With mergeVal
            '    .Merge
            '    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            '    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            '    End With
            Range(rngCell, rngCell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            rngCell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo checkAgain
        End If

    Next
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSz5u.png)

Comment: Could you post an example of the expected output?

Comment: Yes of course sorry I forgot

Comment: @MiteNikolov I proposed an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57774247/11167163) but paste your full code will help me to improve it..

Comment: Sure I will past it right now! @Dorian

Comment: @MiteNikolov I suggested an edit to your post to let the **issue** appears, so it can help other users ;). Kindest regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date
Dim prova As Integer
Dim rngMerge As Range, rngCell As Range, mergeVal As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
StartD = Foglio1.Cells(2, 2)
EndD = Foglio1.Cells(3, 2)
For Column = 1 To EndD - StartD
    Cells(4, Column) = StartD + Column - 1
    prova = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(StartD + Column - 1, 2)
    Cells(5, Column).NumberFormat = prova
    Cells(5, Column).Value = prova
Next Column
```

**Note** that :

`Cells(Column,4)` will browse rows of column 4

`Cells(4,Column)` Will browse column of row 4

Comment: You are the MAGE! I feel so stupid... Thanks a lot! love StackOverFlow

Comment: @MiteNikolov Glad I could help you ! If the issue is solved may I ask you to accept my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using formulas to obtain the dates and weeks. However, the merge of cells would need a loop.

```
Sub TEST_2A()
Dim dIni As Double, dEnd As Double

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")    'change as required
        dIni = .Cells(2, 2)
        dEnd = .Cells(3, 2)

        With .Cells(3, 4).Resize(2, 1 + dEnd - dIni)
            .Cells(1).Value2 = dIni
            .Cells(2).Resize(1, -1 + .Columns.Count).FormulaR1C1 = "=+RC[-1]+1"
            .Rows(1).NumberFormat = "dd\/mm\/yyyy" 'change as required
            .Rows(2).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKNUM(R[-1]C,2)"
            .Value2 = .Value2

    End With: End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah! This also worked! But in my original post there was also the Number of the week(merged) under the days. Could you please update your post?

Comment: Yeah, no looping and use only formula is a great idea!